# Append 1st occurence of x to a list and break loop. However, if y occurs before x, append 1st occurrence of y, then ignore y until 1st occurence of x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am iterating through a column in multiple dataframes `df1['values']`, `df2['values']`, and so on. The elements in `['values']` look like this:

`[3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1]`

I want to loop through the column and append the first occurrence of 4 to a new list and break the loop. However, if 3 occurs before 4, then I want to append that 1st occurrence of 3, ignore any subsequent occurrence of 3, but continue looping until I get to the first occurrence of 4, then break the loop.

So, with the list above:
`[3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1]`

Desired output would be: `[3,4]`

But if the list looked like: `[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1]`

Desired output would be: `[4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
u = df['values'].unique()
u = u[u >= 3]
u = u[:(u == 4).argmax()+1]
```

Output (using first list):

```
>>> u
array([3, 4])
```

Output (using second list):

```
>>> u
array([4])
```